# Maths Coursework - Circle geometry, tangents etc.

Tags: geometry, circles, tangent-line

[image: Picture]

This is a screenshot from the harder part of my coursework. Unfortunately I do not understand it and have no one to explain it.

Comment: There is no question here...

Comment: @copper.hat It was here just a second ago, I'm assuming the OP deleted it

Comment: You left out the screen shot

Comment: Screenshot is there now

Comment: (a) Line through OQ is perpendicular to tangent at Q. you can use this to find the equation of the line through OQ in terms of the coordinate of 0. (b) you know the distance OP - write it in terms of the coordinate of O. (c) and (d) are algebra.

Answer (score 0):

- (a)

The distance $d$, between a point $O(x_0,y_0)$ and a line $ax+by+c=0$ is:

$$d=\frac{|ax_0+by_0+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

In this case $d=r=4\sqrt5$ and the the line is $x-2y+23=0$, then we get:

$$4\sqrt5={|1x_0-2y_0+23|\over \sqrt{1+4}}$$
$$20=|x_0-2y_0+23|$$
$$x_0-2y_0+23=\pm20$$

and we get two linear equations: $x_0-2y_0=-3$ and $x_0-2y_0=-43$. We choose the first solution because it represents a line (containing the center) under the line $x-2y+23=0$.

- (b)

We can use the distance between two points (Pythagoras's theorem):

$$d^2=r^2=(x_P-x_0)^2+(y_P-y_0)^2$$
$$80=(-7-x_0)^2+(-2-y_0)^2$$

- (c)

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
x_0-2y_0=-3\\(-7-x_0)^2+(-2-y_0)^2=80
\end{cases}
\begin{cases}
x_0=2y_0-3\\(7+x_0)^2+(2+y_0)^2=80
\end{cases}
\begin{cases}
x_0=2y_0-3\\(7+2y_0-3)^2+(2+y_0)^2=80
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Now we can solve the second equation $(4+2y_0)^2+(2+y_0)^2=80$:

$$4(2+y_0)^2+(2+y_0)^2=80$$
$$5(2+y_0)^2=80$$
$$2+y_0=\pm4$$

thus we get $y_0=-6$ or $y_0=2$ and $x_0=-15$ or $x_0=1$ respectively. The right center is $O(1,2)$.

- (d)

The equation of a line through $P(-7,-2)$ is: $y+2=m(x+7)$.
We can determine $m$ thinking that the line through $P$ must be tangent to the circle, hence normal to the radius; normal lines have to satisfy $m_1m_2=-1$. Let $m_{OP}$ the angular coefficient of the segment $\overline{OP}$, then:

$$m_{OP}=\frac{y_0-y_P}{x_0-x_P}=\frac{2+2}{1+7}={1\over2}$$

thus $m=-2$.

So the line through $P$ is $y+2=-2(x+7)\longrightarrow y=-2x-16$. The point $R$ is obtained by solving the following system:

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
x-2y+23=0\\y=-2x-16
\end{cases}
\begin{cases}
x+4x+32+23=0\\y=-2x-16
\end{cases}
\begin{cases}
x=-11\\y=6
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

hence $R(-11,6)$.